# The YouTubePlayerView is obscured by com.lbe.security.service.core.client.a.f

Tags: android, youtube

I have created an Android application https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bhajanganga which embedded you tube videos using [YouTubeAndroidPlayerAPI](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/).
The videos play fine in all phones except popular Chinese [Xiaomi](http://www.mi.com/in/) phones. On Xiaomi phones, the following exception is thrown :

> 10-28 12:35:12.870  19717-19717/com.bhajanganga W/YouTubeAndroidPlayerAPI﹕ YouTube video playback stopped due to unauthorized overlay on top of player. The YouTubePlayerView is obscured by com.lbe.security.service.core.client.a.f{42697718 V.E..... ........ 0,0-720,1280}. YouTubePlayerView is completely covered, with the distance in px between each edge of the obscuring view and the YouTubePlayerView being: left: 0, top: 713, right: 0, bottom: 0..

Perhaps a transparent view is overlapping YouTubeAndroidPlayer view.

Can somebody please share sample code to get resource id from com.lbe.security.service.core.client.a.f, so that I can try setting visibility to View.GONE.

Or please suggest any other solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a bug in youtube api. Perhaps a transparent view is overlapping YouTubeAndroidPlayer view. And It seems that Xiaomi has resolved this bug in MIUI version 50.0.

This error is not noticed in MIUI version 50.0 and higher.

https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=6736