# YouTubePlayerView is obscured by com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView

Tags: android, android-layout, youtube, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I have been trying to add a youtube player in a fragment.
had some overlay errors. tried different things and resolved them, now the error is quite awkward. 
I don't know what is wrong here.

the error is *YouTubePlayerView is obscured by com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView*

complete error:

```
W/YouTubeAndroidPlayerAPI: YouTube video playback stopped due to unauthorized overlay on top of player. The YouTubePlayerView is obscured by com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView{2db246cd V.E..... .......D 20,20-596,344}. YouTubePlayerView is completely covered, with the distance in px between each edge of the obscuring view and the YouTubePlayerView being: left: 0, top: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0..
```

MainActivity.java

```
    package onestop.com.youtubefragmenttest;


    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String API_KEY = "AIzaSyDlS41-LGiRTToI4GDDRHglf-VY1wCxvtc";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        YoutubeFragment fragment = new YoutubeFragment();
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        manager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragment, fragment)
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();


    }
}
```

YouTubeFragment.java

```
package onestop.com.youtubefragmenttest;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeInitializationResult;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer.Provider;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerSupportFragment;



/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class YoutubeFragment extends Fragment {

    public static final String API_KEY = "AIzaSyDlS41-LGiRTToI4GDDRHglf-VY1wCxvtc";
    public static final String VIDEO_ID = "lfG2-FFL6fY";

    public YoutubeFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_youtube, container, false);

        YouTubePlayerSupportFragment youTubePlayerFragment = YouTubePlayerSupportFragment.newInstance();

        FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(R.id.youtube_layout, youTubePlayerFragment).commit();

        youTubePlayerFragment.initialize(API_KEY, new OnInitializedListener() {

            // YouTubeプレーヤーの初期化成功
            @Override
            public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider provider, YouTubePlayer yPlayer, boolean wasRestored) {

                if (!wasRestored) {

                    yPlayer.cueVideo(VIDEO_ID);
                }
            }


            // YouTubeプレーヤーの初期化失敗
            @Override
            public void onInitializationFailure(Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult error) {
                // YouTube error
                String errorMessage = error.toString();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.d("errorMessage:", errorMessage);
            }


        });

        return rootView ;

    }

}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="onestop.com.youtubefragmenttest.MainActivity">

    <fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:name="onestop.com.youtubefragmenttest.YoutubeFragment"
        android:id="@+id/fragment"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

fragment_youtube.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/youtube_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:visibility="visible"
    android:padding="10dp">

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: used a frame layout instead of fragment in activity_main.xml

<FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/youtube_frame">

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was, that I was displaying the same video twice.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check if this is a device specific issue, based from this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29765413/5995040) this issue may be due to a transparent view is overlapping YouTubeAndroidPlayer view. Also check your code if there is any overlays when the player is playing.

[*YouTubePlayerFragment*](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayerFragment)

> Note that while videos are playing, this View has a *minimum size of 200x110 dp*. If you make the view any smaller, videos will automatically stop playing. Also, *it is not permitted to overlay this fragment's view with other views while a video is playing*.

**[YouTubePlayerView](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayerView)**

> This view does not support padding. To achieve the same effect, wrap the view in another **`ViewGroup`** or give it margins

Hope this helps!